# How to get cyrillic characters in the booksmarks?

Tags: bookmarks, cyrillic

I have a document written in Russian.  When I compile the document, the table of contents in the document itself is okay, but the cyrillic characters in the bookmarks are not properly encoded (Okular).

[image: broken table of contents]

If I export a document from Libre Office, everything is okay:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I guess you are using pdfTeX? You would have more luck with a unicode engine like XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: If you load hyperref try adding the option `pdfencoding=auto`.

Comment: The `unicode` option for `hyperref` makes bookmarks to be encoded correctly.

Comment: I'm using LuaLatex engine.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan the `unicode` argument doesn't help.
@TeXnician `pdfencoding=auto` helps me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `hyperref` the `unicode` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\setmainfont{Old Standard} % any font that supports Cyrillic

\begin{document}

\section{Азъ}

\subsection{Буки}

\subsection{Веди}

\section{Глаголи}

\subsection{Добро}

\subsection{Есть}

\end{document}
```

What I see with Adobe Acrobat Reader

[image]

Using `bookmark` is recommended, but not mandatory.